# Building multiple user interfaces for same app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native, kotlin

I'm working on a client requirement to have multiple builds of the same app only with basic interface differences between them (logo, colors, labels). In the current scenario, the client already has multiple apps (each one with his own git project) deployed on App Store and Google Play, leading to a high effort to release new updates.

My team needs to unify those apps' codebase, and we are currently looking for a solution to, maybe in the build phase, select which UI we want to deploy. We are building native, but we can consider moving to react native or flutter.

Is there any way to pass build parameters so I can select each color, or each interface the app will be built?

Comment: What's your question? You should be clear what kind of answers you are expecting.

Comment: Is there any way to pass build parameters so I can select each color, or each interface the app will be built?

Comment: Use a single project, with [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants) for each distinct set of artwork/text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with Flavors

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Another option would be to load the config from the backend